# Responsive HTML5 Video - Sizing in iOS

Tags: ios, html, video, safari, responsive-design

we are having trouble displaying Responsive HTML5 video and getting the scale right;

On desktop browsers, the scale is fine - with the video and its poster image scaling perfectly. However on iPhone Safari, the video does not full the width, leaving a black 'border/padding' around.

The CSS;

```
.hero-video {
    /* The Container */
height: 338px;
width: 66.6%;
}
.hero-video video {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="hero-video">
    <video id="intro-video" controls preload="auto" poster="img/trigger-intro.png" width="auto" height="auto">
    <source src="media/intro.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="media/intro.webm" type='video/webm' />
        Your browser does not support this video.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give a visual of the issue? Is it that the poster is not filling the full width of the video tag? BTW I think width="auto" is not valid value you need to set it in pixels (either static or with CSS/JS dynamic values).

Comment: Thanks for your reply - its difficult to share as its client work under NDA at this stage.

The poster doesn't fill the full width of the video. I'll try removing width="auto" and see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

**THIS WORKS FOR ME.**

I am pretty sure you can further change and clean the HTML Markup and CSS Rules but so far this works on iPhone, Android and Kindle Fire Devices.

**For the Video HTML Markup I am using this.**

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" id="background" loop="loop" muted="" poster="solar.jpg" data-autoplay="" playsinline="" height="750" width="1600">
<source src="solar5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**For the CSS I am using this.**

```
#background {
position: relative;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-20%);
transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-20%);
background: url("solar.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 1;
}
.video {
position:relative;
padding-bottom:44.25%;
padding-top:30px;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
```